# SSL pass for dockerized jenkins through dockerized Nginx Reverse proxy won't work

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, jenkins

I have a dockerized jenkins container behind dockerized Nginx reverse proxy that work perfectly with http but throw ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when i try to get jenkins url with https. 
I used auto-signed certificates

my jenkins Dockerfile:

```
LABEL maintainer="barrybhoye@gmail.com"
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx8192m"
ENV JENKINS_OPTS=" --handlerCountMax=300"
USER root
RUN mkdir /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/cache/jenkins
RUN chown -R jenkins:jenkins /var/log/jenkins
USER jenkins
ENV JENKINS_OPTS="--handlerCountMax=300 --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war"
```

my Nginx Dockerfile:

```
LABEL maintainer="barrybhoye@gmail.com"
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install http://nginx.org/packages/centos/7/noarch/RPMS/nginx-release-centos-7-0.el7.ngx.noarch.rpm; yum -y makecache
RUN yum -y install nginx-1.10.1
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY conf/jenkins.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/jenkins.conf
COPY conf/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx"]
```

my docker compose:

```
services:
  master:
    build: ./jenkins-master
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"   
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - jenkins-log:/var/log/jenkins
      - jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/ssl
    networks:
      - jenkins-net
  nginx:
    build: ./jenkins-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - jenkins-net
volumes:
  jenkins-data:
  jenkins-log:
networks:
  jenkins-net:
```

my jenkins conf:

```
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  domaine;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.key;
    ssl_verify_client off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://domaine:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

my nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
   worker_connections  1024;
   use epoll;
   accept_mutex off;
}

http {
   include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

   log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

   access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

   #tcp_nopush     on;

   keepalive_timeout  65;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```